# Pytorch model loading performance

Tags: python, pytorch

Does the performance of loading a model here seem correct?

```
Total time: 5.4545 s
Function: load_model at line 81

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    81                                            @profile
    82                                            def load_model(dirname, device):
    82                                            """ load model from disk """
    83         1         90.0      90.0     0.0       device = torch.device(device)
    84         1         26.0      26.0     0.0       modelfile = os.path.join(dirname, 'model.py')
    85         1          7.0       7.0     0.0       weights = os.path.join(dirname, 'weights_%s.tar' % weights)
    86         1    5379756.0 5379756.0     98.6      model = torch.load(modelfile, map_location=device)
    87         1      72966.0   72966.0     1.3       model.load_state_dict(torch.load(weights, map_location=device))
    88         1       1648.0    1648.0     0.0       model.eval()
    89         1          1.0       1.0     0.0       return model
```

The initial called to load a 26MB model on line 86 is ~100 times slower than loading the 26MB checkpoint on 87 and 5.45 seconds is a lot longer than I would expect?

I'm using pytorch 1.2 and a `device="cuda"` and have confirmed the same performance with 1.3.1. Adding in calls to sync confirms that all of the time is actually spend in `torch.load`.

```
    86         1    5395545.0 5395545.0     98.6      model = torch.load(modelfile, map_location=device)
    87         1         76.0      76.0      0.0      torch.cuda.synchronize(device=device)
    88         1      72403.0   72403.0      1.3      model.load_state_dict(torch.load(weights, map_location=device))
    89         1         52.0      52.0      0.0      torch.cuda.synchronize(device=device)
    90         1       1640.0    1640.0      0.0      model.eval()
    91         1         21.0      21.0      0.0      torch.cuda.synchronize(device=device)
```

Am I doing something wrong here or is this typical?

Comment: It is really depend what size is your model. I work with ~1GB models that loading them takes about 40 sec if I recall correctly.

Comment: Seems typical. A common bottleneck for many applications is hard disk access which is likely the reason for the times you're seeing. If the tensors are saved as cuda tensors then there's an additional operation which requires transferring the weights to GPUs and potentially initializing some driver level cuda stuff.

Comment: @jodag maybe consider adding your comment as an answer.